Decomposition of $\operatorname{Sp}_{2n}(\mathbb{C})$-rep $\operatorname{Sym}^2(\Gamma_{0,1})$
I want to understand a specific $\operatorname{Sp}_{2n}(\mathbb{C})$ representation. I'll use the notation for irreduble representations used in Fulton-Harris. Some examples using this notation:

$\Gamma_0 = \mathbb{C}$
$\Gamma_1$ is the standard representation
$\Gamma_{0,1} = (\bigwedge^2 \Gamma_1) / \mathbb{C}$
$\Gamma_n = \operatorname{Sym}^n(\Gamma_1)$
$\bigwedge^4 \Gamma_1 = \Gamma_{0,0,0,1} \oplus \Gamma_{0,1} \oplus \mathbb{C}$

Now, I want to understand the representation $\operatorname{Sp}_{2n}(\mathbb{C})$-rep $\operatorname{Sym}^2(\Gamma_{0,1})$. It decomposes into the following irreducible representations $$\mathbb{C} \oplus \Gamma_{0,1} \oplus \Gamma_{0,0,0,1} \oplus \Gamma_{0,2}.$$
Letting $(a \wedge b) \leftrightarrow (c \wedge d) := (a \wedge b) \otimes (c \wedge d) + (c \wedge d) \otimes (a \wedge b)$, define the map $$p: \operatorname{Sym}^2(\Gamma_{0,1}) \rightarrow \bigwedge^4 \Gamma_1$$ by $(a \wedge b) \leftrightarrow (c \wedge d) \mapsto a \wedge b \wedge c \wedge d$. Based on some pattern recognition from reading about other $\operatorname{Sp}_{2n}(\mathbb{C})$-reps, I would guess that $\operatorname{ker}(p) = \Gamma_{0,2}$.
My questions are:

Am I correct that $\operatorname{ker}(p) = \Gamma_{0,2}$?
If I am correct, how can I verify this more rigorously?
If I am wrong, can you help me understand how $\Gamma_{0,2}$ sits inside $\operatorname{Sym}^2(\Gamma_{0,1})$?

